# Can anyone help me how to half size the circleplayer skin of jplayer?

Tags: jquery, css, jplayer

Using the css file of circle player I modified it to half size the circle player. What I did is change the values in css to half size. see code example below:

```
.cp-container.small {
    position: relative;
    width: 52px !important;
    height: 52px !important;
    background: url("bgr.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 24px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.cp-container :focus {
    border:none; 
    outline:0;
}

.cp-buffer-1.small,
.cp-buffer-2.small,
.cp-progress-1.small,
.cp-progress-2.small {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 52px !important;
    height: 52px !important;
    clip: rect(0px,26px,52px,0px) !important;

    -moz-border-radius: 52px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
    border-radius: 52px;
}

.cp-buffer-1.small,
.cp-buffer-2.small {
    background: url("buffer.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
} 


/* FALLBACK for .progress
 * (24 steps starting from 1hr filled progress, Decrease second value by 104px for next step)
 * (It needs the container selector to work. Or use div)
 */ 

.cp-container .cp-fallback.small {
    background: url("progress_sprite-green.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 104px !important; 
}

/* .cp-progress-1,
.cp-progress-2 {
    background: url("progress.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
} */

.cp-progress-1.green.small,
.cp-progress-2.green.small{
    background: url("progress-green.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-progress-1.blue.small,
.cp-progress-2.blue.small{
    background: url("progress-blue.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-progress-1.red.small,
.cp-progress-2.red.small{
    background: url("progress-red.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-buffer-holder.small,
.cp-progress-holder.small,
.cp-circle-control.small {
    position:absolute;
    width: 52px !important;
    height: 52px !important;
} 

.cp-circle-control {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.cp-buffer-holder.small,
.cp-progress-holder.small {
    clip:rect(0px,52px,52px,26px) !important;
    display:none;
}


/* This is needed when progress is greater than 50% or for fallback */

.cp-buffer-holder.cp-gt50,
.cp-progress-holder.cp-gt50,
.cp-progress.cp-fallback{
    clip:rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}  

.cp-controls.small {
    margin:0;
    padding: 13px !important;
}

.cp-controls li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;

    /*IE Fix*/  
    position: absolute;
}

.cp-controls.small li a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:25px !important;
    height:25px !important;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    z-index:1;      
}

/* .cp-controls .cp-play {
    background: url("controls.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
} */

.cp-controls .cp-play.green.small {
    background: url("controls-green.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-play.red.small {
    background: url("controls-red.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-play.blue.small {
    background: url("controls-blue.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
}



.cp-controls .cp-play.green.small:hover{
    background: url("controls-green.jpg") -25px 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-play.red.small:hover {
    background: url("controls-red.jpg") -25px 0 no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-play.blue.small:hover {
    background: url("controls-blue.jpg") -25px 0 no-repeat;
}

/* .cp-controls .cp-pause {
    background: url("controls.jpg") 0 -50px no-repeat;
} */

.cp-controls .cp-pause.green.small{
    background: url("controls-green.jpg") 0 -25px no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-pause.red.small{
    background: url("controls-red.jpg") 0 -25px no-repeat;
}

.cp-controls .cp-pause.blue.small {
    background: url("controls-blue.jpg") 0 -25px no-repeat;
}

/* .cp-controls .cp-pause:hover {
    background: url("controls.jpg") -50px -50px no-repeat;
} */

.cp-controls .cp-pause.green.small:hover {
    background: url("controls-green.jpg") -25px -25px no-repeat !important;
}

.cp-controls .cp-pause.red.small:hover {
    background: url("controls-red.jpg") -25px -25px no-repeat !important;
}

.cp-controls .cp-pause.blue.small:hover {
    background: url("controls-blue.jpg") -25px -25px no-repeat !important;
}

.cp-jplayer {
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
}
```

I tested it on firefox works ok, but on IE not. Well I hope you help out with this problem.

Comment: Do you have a URL? Can you be more specific on what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your Positions don't seem to be halved as well:

```
background-position: 0 104px !important;
```

The above should be cut in half. I can send you the working half-sized files I made if you'd like!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use css's zoom property. Do not resize images nor change css. Just add `zoom: 50%;` to .cp-container

Comment: Very nice solution for some browsers, but `zoom` is non-standard and not supported by all browsers.

Comment: zoom 50% nicely reduce size, but click listener off-center, how to fix that?

Comment: Please anyone can answer on that.. i have the same question.. zoom 50% works fine.. click listener is off-center